# Не выводятся посетители "онлайн" в чате

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Довожу до ума небольшой чатик, который писал, и столкнулся со следующей трудностью - хотел вывести пользователей, что онлайн в чате, но никак не получается. Для того чтобы определить пользователя онлайн, я сначала создал миграцию в базе данных и добавил к модели пользователя атрибут `last_online`: `add_last_online_to_users last_online:datetime`. Затем я добавил в класс `User` метод `online_now`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages, dependent: :delete_all
    class << self
        def from_omniauth(auth)
            provider = auth.provider
            uid = auth.uid
            info = auth.info.symbolize_keys!
            user = User.find_or_initialize_by(uid: uid, provider: provider)
            user.name = info.name
            user.avatar_url = info.image
            user.profile_url = info.urls.send(provider.capitalize.to_sym)
            user.save!
            user
        end
        def online_now
            where("last_online > ?", 15.minutes.ago)
        end
    end
end
```

и в `application_controller.rb`:

```
def show_online
    @users = User.online_now
end
```

Также, в контроллерах, что отвечают за создание новой сессии и отправку сообщения, я указал условие для обновления атрибута `last_online`

`messages_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
        if current_user
            @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
            @message.save
            current_user.update_attributes(last_online: Time.now)
            format.html{redirect_to root_path}
            format.js
        else
            format.html{redirect_to root_path}
            format.js {render nothing: true}
        end
    end
end
```

`sessions_controller.rb`

```
def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    cookies[:user_id] = user.id
    user.update_attributes(last_online: Time.now)
end
```

и, наконец, во вьюхе:

```
<ul>
    <%= @users.each do |user| %>
        <li><%= user.name %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Проверял через консоль `User.online_now` - юзер, что в данный момент зашел в чат или отправил сообщение, есть, но в списке его нет.

Comment: И-и... Вы список-то обновляете в браузере? Ну вы конечно выбрали первый проект на Rails, чат... Это не та технология, на которой стоит таким заниматься.

Comment: @D-side дело в том, что после авторизации, у меня идет редирект на страницу, где список, то есть страница со списком обновляется. Но в нем пусто :( а по поводу первого проекта - я просто написал пару простеньких бложиков, вот и захотелось чего поинтереснее

Comment: Чат на рельсах это больше борьба с технологией, чем творчество :) Но дело ваше. Берите `pry`, смотрите, что в `@users` и что при этом в `User.online_now`.

Comment: 1. `user.update_attributes(last_online: Time.now)` а вот это вообще отрабатывает? Может там пользователь невалидный. В базе если посмотреть, что в этом поле у авторизованного пользователя?
2. `show_online` а где это вообще вызывается?

Comment: @anoam 1. отрабатывает, в базе находит пользователя с аттрибутом `last_online`. 2. `show_online` вызывается в общей вьюхе, через `@users.each`

Comment: @D-side просто я немного влюбился в Ruby, и теперь у меня жуткое желание `исследовать границы возможного`, как бы сказал какой-нибудь возрастной психолог :) думаю, это распространенная особенность новичков. да и чешутся в одном месте воспоминания о нежной юности с локалкой, чатом CommFort и хабом DC++ :D

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94, `2. show_online вызывается в общей вьюхе, через @users.each`
- это как? что на вьюхе этот код отрабатывает означает только что в `@users` есть что-то, у чего есть метод `each` (массив/хэш/релейшен/т.д.). Но где вызывается конкретно метод `show_online` из представленного неясно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вы нигде так и не вызвали метод show_online, поэтому @users  у вас пустой. С другой стороны, тогда должна возникать ошибка на each. Добавьте код, в котором вы вызываете show_online для конкретного контроллера?